# Uneven walls, not solid

Tags: ultimaker-cura

I'm using Cura 4.5.0 and an Ultimaker S5

The walls in my model are coming out not solid. I don't have a clue why.

[image]

[image]

When I open the STL in Sketchup it has all these weird lines. I don't know how they got there and I don't know how to get rid of them.

[image]

Comment: The lines are not a problem, they come from being STL - which is all triangles.

Comment: What is the width of the walls, what is your nozzle, what is your line widths?

Comment: Nozzle 0.4, walls 1.75mm. Running Cura on recommended 0.2 line

Comment: What's the retraction distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Triangles?!

First of all, the triangles on the STL are not a problem - they are just how STL is defined: a mesh of triangles. you can't save anything but triangles in STL, so let's not bother with that item but the actual elephant in the room: the print.

## Underextrusion

### Step 1: proper settings

It shows signs of underextrusion. And I can exactly tell you where part of it comes from: You have set the line width to *below* the nozzle width. However, the line width should be best 10% *larger* than the nozzle. **All** of these lines should read between 0.4 to (as I have set it) 0.45 mm:

[image]

With a 10% wider line planned into, it is not necessary to have an extra initial layer line width of more than 100 %, but it can help in adhesion.

### Step 2: Other issues?!

There might be other issues at work, though they will show up after setting the width much better. The following two strike me as most likely if the problem persists with the now considerable increased flow:

- The retraction and/or retraction speed might be set too high.
- mechanical issues of the extruder system, for example, worn gears or uneven pressure against the gear due to damaged parts.

Comment: I've done the settings by your recomendation but when i slice it it still shows the inproper infill of the walls –
But when i increase the layer hight to 0.25mm and slice it it looks fine.
Something wierd is going on. Because when I then change it back to 0.2mm layer hight it looks fine. Must cache something. So it seems that your setting will work.

Many thanks!

Comment: @Tobbe note that you can set "Initial layer width" to 100% too.

Comment: This looks more like localized underextrusion due to loss of material. Line widths down to 0.35 or even 0.3 are unconventional but should be okay. I've even printed 0.2 mm lines using a standard 0.4 mm nozzle and didn't have any problems with extrusion consistency.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Possibly... Retraction!

Comment: @Trish: Yeah that would be my first guess, but you can also end up with loss of material from combing over infill, or can have underextrusion due to coasting or other weird slicer options.

Comment: The 0.35 mm is the default width for Ultimaker machines and works perfectly, I've printed kilometers of filament with the default settings without a problem.

Comment: Maybe drop the layer height to 0.18 .  I've seen claims that multiples of the default 0.06 work better.  Or maybe not  :-)